# MSBuild: How to exclude zero length files?

Tags: msbuild

I use some task that works with files (Copy for example), but I want to exclude all files that are empty (0 bytes length). Is there a syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have yo write a custom task for this. If you are using MSBuild 4, then you can also create an Inline Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx).